# wiring the Air Conditioner plug

Tags: wiring, rewire

Did I wire this correctly?

My understanding is that strapped wire (green/yellow) is ground, so I connected it to the middle. And blue/brown doesn't really matter which way they go, since for alternating current positive/negative doesn't really matter.

[image]

The flip side of the plug above

[image]

And the original stock plug that I'm replacing

[image]

Comment: "And blue/brown doesn't really matter which way they go." does it? We don't even know what kind of plug that is, which country, what mains power it runs on and what regulations for your country/area apply...

Comment: The cord clamp (the grey part) should be clamping the cord, not the wires. *If* the live (brown) and neutral (blue) should be the same way round as in the UK, then they are the wrong way round. We need to know what country you are in.

Comment: Ground is not allowed to be cut short like yours where I live. It needs to be so long that if you forcefully pull out the entire cable from the plug, ground is that last one to loose contact.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Easy to say :) air conditioner make is Daewoo, my area is Republic of Georgia, and wire + plug is made in Turkey.

Comment: @AndrewMorton it is clamping the cord, its just 1 mm behind the cord clamp so in photo it seems as if only 3 wires are clamped.

Comment: @sandrodz - You should try to rearrange to have the strain relief clamp be fully over the jacket of the cord. With the way you have it the cord jacket can slip out of the clamp much easier than if 3mm of the cord jacket were to extend beyond the clamp.

Comment: Please would you show us a photo of the other side of the plug so that we can see if it is a Schuko type E or Schuko type F plug. A photo of the socket it will be plugged into might also be useful.

Comment: @AndrewMorton added the other side + plug I'm replacing (stock version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally we *do* care about hot vs neutral, even though they are AC.  That is because the system is designed so neutral is *near* earth potential, so it is essentially non-hazardous except if something has failed.  Machines are wired with that in mind, for instance a screw-base lamp will wire neutral to the more-easily-touched shell.

However, your particular plug type is designed to be symmetrical - it can be flipped over, reversing hot and neutral.  This defeats the purpose of separating hot and neutral, and therefore requires a double insulated appliance.  If the air conditioner originally had a keyed plug, this might matter because it might not be double insulated. The good news is the machine probably has a metal chassis, which will at least protect you from shock - if your ground wire is solid as a rock!  If it's not, an insulation failure could energize the chassis of the machine.

If you can't ground the machine reliably, GFCI aka RCD will greatly reduce that risk.

Comment: Hi, added more photos. Does it change your answer?

Comment: @sandrodz Nope, the new plug is not able to be polarized.  The old one is polarized if it's plugged into [this type here](http://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plugs-and-sockets/e/), but I gather you don't have that type in Georgia.

Comment: no we don't have those. We have two hole ones.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking up / googling the colour codes for your area. For instance: -

[image]

Then google your plug wiring information to see which one is regarded as live (hot) and which one is regarded as neutral. You shouldn't swap live and neutral - stick to convention.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information on the internet about wiring up plugs. You should have: Yellow/Green as earth, 
Blue to Neutral
Brown to Live.

A good webpage to follow would be this one: https://www.rospa.com/home-safety/uk/northern-ireland/electricity/plugs-fuses/wiring-plugs/

Comes with step by step instructions, visual aids and what to do if you are replacing a plug with the 'old' colours in.

If you are still in any doubt, then just take another one apart and have a quick check!

**EDIT** 
That was assuming a UK plug..... My bad, should have asked first! but either way, information is freely available, and my last point still stands!

Answer (score 0):

You have wired it correctly according to [Europe colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_wiring#Colour_coding_of_wiring_by_region). Which is where you are.

However, two remarks on your work:

1. Earth should always be the longest wire in the plug.
   When you give a hard pull on the wire, earth should be the last wire to let go. This ensures the GFCI (RCD) will trip when any live wire touches chassis. Instead f the chassis becoming live
2. Most devices do not care about Live/Neutral polarity.
   Except for gas heaters or some high power devices. Read the manual of the device.

Comment: Air conditioner can be considered a high power device?

Comment: @sandrodz Yes. But I don't think they care about polarity.